# Sweet numbers , problems with checking if the number is sweet

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

We put a range from keyboard from what number to what number we want to search the ''Sweet number''. 
One number is sweet if each of the digits is an even number. So I started and don't know how to go on

```
int min,max,i,sweetnumber;
scanf("%d%d",&min,&max);
for(i=min;i<=max;i++)
{
  // and now what ? i don't know if the number is three-digit or four-digit or five digit so i can check a digit by digit .. Someone help ! 
}
```

Comment: OK, how can you get the rightmost digit of  decimal number? Mathematically.

Comment: Eugene is inviting you to a hike along the path of the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions I recommend to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need something like the following

```
for ( i = min; i <= max; i++ )
{
    int tmp = i;

    while ( tmp != 0 && tmp % 10 % 2 == 0 ) tmp /= 10;

    if ( tmp == 0 ) printf( "%d is a sweet number\n", i );
}
```

Comment: damn man you helped me a lot ty

Comment: And yes if you can explain me how you come to here

Comment: @World What do you mean? Do you mean the loop? Inside the loop each digit of the number is checked whether it is even. This expression tmp % 10 gives the current  last digit and then checks whether it is even tmp % 10 % 2 == 0

Comment: @World Investigate the code yourself.

Comment: Ok vlad now i get it thank you a lot <3